# Failure adding Spring HATEOAS to pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, hateoas

so i'm following a tutorial about building Restful services with spring boot and i have to add HATEOAS dependency to pom.xml but it didn't work !!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.project</groupId>
 <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Project</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot library management system</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

and this is what i get as error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SONeO.png)

while my goal is to use Resource <>  from import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource which couldn't be imported ! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2yXN.png)

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resource` has been renamed to `EntityModel` in Spring Hateoas 1.0, so you are looking for `org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel`

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.changes.representation-models:

> The ResourceSupport/Resource/Resources/PagedResources group of classes
>   never really felt appropriately named. After all, these types do not
>   actually manifest resources but rather representation models that can
>   be enriched with hypermedia information and affordances. Here’s how
>   new names map to the old ones:
>
> ResourceSupport is now RepresentationModel
>
> Resource is now EntityModel
>
> Resources is now CollectionModel
>
> PagedResources is now PagedModel

Comment: Thank you for your help ❤️